# How to make non standard shape buttons, non clickable outside of it's border

Tags: html, css, button

I want to be able to create buttons on the web page using html and css. 
The buttons should be of non standard shape, like rectangular from one side and circular from another, etc.

The first question is how to do it, and the second is, how to make it so that it will not be clickable if clicked little outside of it's rounded border.
Here is CSS code to make the button circular,

```
.buttons
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

If you try this code, and click outside of the button's circular area, then it will click, however I want it not to be clicable if not clicked inside of it's border.

Comment: As a sidenote - on an element of X pixels wide/high, the `border-radius` cannot be higher than X/2 since it's applied on both ends. Only if specifying all corners separately does it make sense to go higher. Iow `border-radius:25px` would also do the job here and be more correct for making a circle.

Comment: @Niels Setting a border radius of `100%` is a good idea if you _always_ want the rounded corners to fill an edge

Comment: @Bojangles that's not what's being done here though  :)  The exact code given here, while completely valid, is kind of 'flawed', like specifying `max-width:100px;width:120px;` on an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is outside your control. When applying `border-radius` to an element, by all means it's still rectangular in the box model - all you are applying is a different rendering style which makes it *look* rounded. The standards also don't specify what this means for the clicking area of the element.

Some more recent browsers appear to respect `border-radius` for click areas, but it's up to the browser vendor to implement it or not, and you have no **definitive** influence over it without hacking some Javascript in there to calculate where the user clicked.

### UPDATE:

I tried it with [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhMe5/), and the results are funny:

- Firefox latest stable sees a rectangle
- Chrome latest beta sees a rectangle
- IE10 (!!!) 'correctly' ignores clicks outside the shape

As said, it's undefined behaviour in the standards so consider it a bonus if it works.

Comment: If you are using flash then it is possible to make some non standard shapes buttons, which are pressed only if clicked within it's border, if I need the same thing without using flash, is there any frameworks to do it easily, not making those calculations of where the button was clicked manually on Javascript?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, it's just a limitation of HTML that no one really seems to care about. Not too sure why you do either, it's not that much of a problem is it?  :)

Comment: It will be a problem if you have several buttons with non standard shape which you want to place one after another with no empty space between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control such thing in HTML. As @Niels said, It's up to the vendor.

However, I think you can do that in SVG.