# prevent link from being reached outside circle borders

Tags: html, css

I have a set of linked images inside a circle container with overflow hidden. The problem is that I can still hover on the links outside the circle borders. can anyone help with this? Here's a sample code of what I mean: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5j5kd36q/3/)

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#0">
    <img src="https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1462903004115-f8e27d6a3985" alt="image">
  </a>
</div>

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I see your code working fine, which you want, see the link: http://prntscr.com/cmn0m0

Comment: Your code is working fine. I added a `google.com` `href` to your  a element and also included a simple `:hover` for show. You will see outside of the `container` class it won't grow and also wont go to link if clicked. [PEN HERE](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/zKwdvE)

Comment: I can reproduce this issue in Safari 9, but not Chrome 53 or Firefox 48.

Comment: @showdev I just checked firefox and it's working perfectly fine. Do you happen to know a fix for the other browsers, at least Safari and Chrome?

Comment: You may need to use JavaScript to make it reliable across browsers. See [Make Non-Standard Shape Buttons Non-Clickable Outside of It's Border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383745/how-to-make-non-standard-shape-buttons-non-clickable-outside-of-its-border) and [Button Border Radius and Cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760692/button-border-radius-and-cursor). Here's a JavaScript idea: [Hover and Click Trigger for Circular Elements with jQuery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/22/hover-and-click-trigger-circular-elements/).